# "Error getting a Request Token: Bad request" when setting up online accounts

Tags: online-accounts

I have just installed 11.10 version and I cannot setup my online account. I installed Gnome Do and contacts but I am having problems about the online account.

I got the error message below:

> Error getting a Request Token: Bad Request

Comment: Who is this online account with? Can you share the URL you are attempting to use?
<br/>Are you refering to Ubuntu one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea exactly as stated and more precisely make sure your time is right.A better approach to this will be to select the **Directly from Internet** option in set time.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your date and time in the system clock is right.

Comment: Yap; same thing happened to me on a computer I upgraded from Fedora 15 -> 16 pre-release where somehow the transition to systemd sets the system clock with the wrong TZ offset at every boot.

Comment: Yep, same issue here. The time was off. Quickly corrected by setting correct timezone and time. Thanks RockrKnight.